# Laravel queue is not doing job in the background

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-queue

I am trying to use laravel queue to send bulk emails. So far I have written down the logic and it works fine, but the problem is that when I wrote the logic in controller it takes a lot of time so I thought of using jobs but again the problem persists.

**My Problem**

My problem is that I am not able send the email in background even if I am using queue.

**Controller**

```
    public function newsletter(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->all());
        dispatch(new SendEmail($request));

        Session::flash('message', 'Email Sent');
        Session::flash('class', 'success');
        return redirect()->route('news');
    }
```

**Jobs**

```
    public function handle(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $data = array(
            'message' => $request->message,
            'subject' => $request->subject,
            'file' => $request->file("file")
        );
        
        $teachingLevel = $request->highest_teaching_level;
        $school = $request->school;
        $province = $request->province;
        $district = $request->district;

        $subject = $request->subject;

        if ($teachingLevel != "" && $school != "" && $province != "" && $district != "") {
            $email = User::where('highest_teaching_level', $teachingLevel)->where('current_school_name', $school)->where('address','LIKE', '%'.$province.'%')->where('address','LIKE', '%'.$district.'%')->pluck('email');
        }else{
        $email = User::pluck('email');
        }
        
        foreach($email as $e)
        {
            Mail::to($e)->send(new NewsLetter($data, $subject));
        }
    }
```

The email is sent but it doesn't happen in the background. Maybe it has to do with the way I have passed `$request` variable in the `handle()` function.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with the "sync" queue driver?

Comment: @TariqImtinan No, I have used database queue.

Comment: try with the "sync" driver then, hope it'll help you to find out the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I'm using Laravel jobs in my project:

**SampleJob.php**

```php
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use App\Services\SampleService;

class SampleJob implements ShouldQueue {
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
  
  // if you omit this value, you'll be in trouble, believe me
  public $tries = 1; 

  private $param;

  public function __construct($param) {
    $this->param = $param;
  }

  public function handle(SampleService $service) {
    // do something with $this->param
    // Also, notice that you can type hint classes in handle function declaration for DI
    $service->doSomething($this->param);
  }
  
}
```

**SampleController.php**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Jobs\SampleJob;


class SampleController extends Controller {
    
  public function sampleMethod(Request $request) {
    $param = $request->input('param');
    SampleJob::dispatch($param); // $param will be passed to SampleJob constructor
    // ...
  }

}
```

**A few points worth to note are:**

- Read the comments in my code snippets
- If you use db-based queue, migrate first with `php artisan queue:table && php artisan migrate`
- Create jobs with artisan command: `php artisan make:job Sample`
- Don't forget to run queue worker: `php artisan queue:work`. To make it run in background: `sudo nohup php artisan queue:work > ./storage/logs/queue-worker.log &`
- Highly recommended: In deployment, use [Supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#supervisor-configuration) to keep `php artisan queue:work` running in the background
- If you manage to make the job work, all delayed (queued but not handled because of misconfiguration or not starting queue worker) works will be instantly executed.

**Common pitfalls:**

- If you don't set `$tries` param, and somehow your job throws an error, laravel will try to retry that job again and again until your database is down :(
- If http user and php user is different, and if you used `Log` in your job, nine out of ten times you face permission problem on `storage` directory. To avoid this problem, add `'permission' => '0666'` to your log channel setting in `config/logging.php`
- Queue worker does not detect your code change, thus restart queue worker by `php artisan queue:restart` after you make some change to code base.

My laravel version: 5.8

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to work with “database” connection is neccesary to run the next migrations:

```
php artisan queue:table

php artisan migrate
```

Also have an Event and a Listener that implements the “ShouldQueue” interface, and by last register the event associated with the listener or listeners in your “providers/EventProvider.php” path and in “EventProvider.php” file add your event and listeners with the next notation as example:

```
protected $listen = [
  Registered::class => [
    SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
  ],
];
```

Its important to understant few points related to following queue:restart command

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

For that to work, you need to be running the Queue Listener:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Ref: https://medium.com/ariel-mejia-dev/run-queues-in-the-background-on-development-in-laravel-8d697d812f29